# Returning S3 to stock - What bad can happen?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, odin

Its been a while ( 3 and a half years, in fact) Since I last returned a device to stock. Shamefully, I don't remember the process (I do remember that PC kies is the enemy, however.) I am currently Following a guide from our XDA lads [here.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/general/fix-s3-to-factory-unroot-stock-recovery-t2323847) Now, the method is clear, but where and how can I make this go really, really wrong? (So I don't go wrong)

Apologies for such a..... noobish question, especially from someone who considers themself a 'expert' at Samsung modding, but it has been so long. I barely rembered my sammobile login. Also, I guess this is Samsung UN-modding, soooooooo....... I win?

Comment: As far as I can remember, downgrading from >=4.3 breaks the radio. Also, Odin wipes anything inside the internal storage (even **/data/media**).

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman well, it's a good job it was still on android 4.3, eh? It was just running CM with a heap of personal tweaks.

Comment: BUT NO CUSTOM KERNEL. I am very specific about that.